# Repeat Image along x axis in libgdx game for Android

Tags: java, android, textures, libgdx

I am implementing one game where I want to repeat one image along x direction.I searched for it on the web but could not get the correct approach. There is a grass image and I want to repeat it all along the ground in x direction.

Kindly provide some suggestions and possible ways to do it.

I am using following code to draw Image inside render method.

```
  spriteBatch.draw(grass, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Check out this might help you. http://javamilf.blogspot.in/2013/07/libgdx-repeating-background-image.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try a simple for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i <= Gdx.graphics.getWidth(); i += grass.getWidth() {
    spriteBatch.draw(grass, i, 0);
}
```

I assume `grass`is an instance of `Sprite`. If that doesn't work, don't hesitate to comment back.

Comment: grass is a texture.Thanks for taking interest.

Comment: @JigarPandya this code snipet will still work, as getWidth() is a method inherited from Texture